# Socket.io - "Session ID unknown" problem when try to hanle websocket commuication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, sockets

I am working on a project that involves a React client using Socket.io for real-time communication with a Node.js server. The server handles code blocks, and each code block has its own room to manage collaborative editing.

am encountering an issue where, upon emitting events to rooms, I receive a "session id unknown" error. This error seems to indicate a problem with identifying the session associated with a particular socket.

This is my server side:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");


const cors = require("cors");
const connectDB = require('./configs/db');
const codeBlockRouter = require('./routers/codeBlockRouter');
const users = require('./routers/userRouter')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

// routers
app.use('/codeblocks', codeBlockRouter)
app.use('/users', users)

connectDB();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://online-coding-web-client.vercel.app",//client
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

let userCount = 0;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  const user = `${++userCount}`;

  console.log(`User connected: user${user}`);
  socket.emit("user_connected", { user });

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    console.log(`User joined room: ${data}`);
    socket.join(data);

  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${data.messageText} from user ${data.user}`);
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive_message", { ...data, user });
  });


  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`User disconnected: user${user}`);
  });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

This is my client side:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io(serverURL, {
  withCredentials: true
})

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("join_room", codeBlockId);
  }, [codeBlockId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user_connected", (data) => {
      setUser(data.user);
    });
  }, [socket]);


  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setText(data.messageText);

    });
  }, [socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (messageText) => {
    socket.emit("send_message", { messageText, user });
  };
```

I suspect that the issue may be related to how I am handling socket connections, disconnections, or room management. Could someone please review the provided code snippets and help me identify what might be causing the "session id unknown" error?

Comment: which line of your code is the first that comes up in the stack trace for that error